# error in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a query by linq in NHibernate 3.1

```
var q = from Person p in SessionInstance.Query<Person>()
                    select p;
return q.ToList();
```

it has  this error:
**" Specified method is not supported. "**

What is problem?

Stacktrace is :

```
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.Process(IASTNode tree)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process(IASTNode ast, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: can you provide a more complete stacktrace?

Comment: I forget it. Problem is in q.Tolist()

Comment: Of course it is a runtime error.

Comment: can you show stacktrace?

Comment: Stacktrace added to question!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard a guess and say that `.Query<Person>()` is not a supported method.

If it isn't, then, to my knowledge, there is no way you can *make* it supported; you would need to look for an alternative for querying / gathering data to be queried.

Comment: It is a simple query. Why is not supported?   How must Correct this Methode?

Comment: It's not the query itself at fault, but seemingly the nhibernate method.

Comment: I forget it. Problem is in q.Tolist()

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to add using:

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
```

`Query<T>` is an extension method in the NHibernate.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In NHibernate you can use `SessionInstance.Linq`. Tried that?

```
var q = from Person p in SessionInstance.Linq<Person>()
        select p;
```

Comment: Ok. I test it beforehand. in NH 3.1 is not correct. In NH 3.1 This methode changed to Query<Person>() Instead of Linq<Person>()

Comment: I'm not sure.
But
I asked it before,
Others said it.  Linq<Person>() in NH3.1 has 1 compile error, but Query<Person>() has 1 runtime error.